# SQLAlchemy not including CTEs in DELETE

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm attempting to utilize a CTE with a `DELETE` in SQLAlchemy (core).  So far, my attempts have been unsuccessful whereby the CTE is not being included in the compiled SQL statement.  Ultimately, this will be run against a PostgreSQL database, which supports this kind of statement.

Python code of a contrived example:

```py
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql
metadata = MetaData()
tbl = Table('foo', metadata,
        Column('id', Integer, primary_key = True),
        Column('name', String)
    )

mycte = select([tbl.c.name]).where(tbl.c.id == 123).cte('ctetbl')
delete_stmt = tbl.delete().where(tbl.c.name == mycte.c.name)
print("Regular:", delete_stmt.compile())
print("Postgres:", delete_stmt.compile(dialect = postgresql.dialect()))
```

What I'm expecting is (or something like):

```sql
WITH ctetbl AS (
    SELECT name FROM foo
    WHERE id = 123
)
DELETE FROM foo WHERE foo.name = ctetbl.name
```

What I'm getting is:

```sql
DELETE FROM foo WHERE foo.name = ctetbl.name
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```
WITH ctetbl AS (
    SELECT name FROM foo
    WHERE id = 123
)
DELETE FROM foo WHERE foo.name = ctetbl.name
```

you've not actually included the CTE as a source table in the DELETE statement. Something similar happens in your SQLAlchemy statement due to [no support for USING clause](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issues/959) and that throws the compiler off. You could [add support for it with a compiler extension](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy/cIvgH2y01_o):

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import Delete, Update
import re

@compiles(Delete, 'postgresql')
def compile_delete(element, compiler, **kw):
    using_clause = None
    extra_froms = Update._extra_froms.__get__(element)

    if extra_froms:
        # Pre-compile extra_froms in order to populate CTEs before
        # compiling the delete statement itself
        using_clause = "USING %s" % ', '.join(
            compiler.process(fr, asfrom=True, **kw)
            for fr in extra_froms
        )

    text = compiler.visit_delete(element, **kw)

    if using_clause:
        # NOTE: This will blow up badly, if your CTEs also
        # contain DELETE statements.
        text = re.sub(
            r"(DELETE FROM \S+)",
            lambda m: "%s %s" % (m.group(1), using_clause),
            text
        )

    return text
```

and then

```
delete_stmt = tbl.delete().where(tbl.c.name == mycte.c.name)
```

will compile as

```
WITH ctetbl AS 
(SELECT foo.name AS name 
FROM foo
WHERE foo.id = %(id_1)s)
 DELETE FROM foo USING ctetbl WHERE foo.name = ctetbl.name
```

Using USING you could do a self-join as well:

```
   ...: tbl_alias = tbl.alias()
   ...: delete_stmt = tbl.delete().\
   ...:     where(tbl.c.name == tbl_alias.c.name).\
   ...:     where(tbl_alias.c.id == 123)
   ...: 
   ...: print("Postgres:", delete_stmt.compile(dialect = postgresql.dialect()))
   ...: 
Postgres: DELETE FROM foo USING foo AS foo_1 WHERE foo.name = foo_1.name AND foo_1.id = %(id_1)s
```

---

Of course you could've also referenced the CTE with a scalar sub-select without having the compiler extension in place:

```
   ...: delete_stmt = tbl.delete().where(tbl.c.name == mycte.select().as_scalar())
   ...: 
   ...: print("Postgres:", delete_stmt.compile(dialect = postgresql.dialect()))
Postgres: WITH ctetbl AS 
(SELECT foo.name AS name 
FROM foo 
WHERE foo.id = %(id_1)s)
 DELETE FROM foo WHERE foo.name = (SELECT ctetbl.name 
FROM ctetbl)
```

but where's the fun in that...

Comment: Raise issue in the tracker?

Comment: The first link is actually the (very old) open issue about this.

Comment: Regarding the scalar sub-select, that makes sense.  In my own case, I'm selecting from multiple tables, so I guess my example doesn't exactly line up with what I'm working with, but the compiler extension is a step in the right direction.  Glad to know that this is a missing feature of SQLAlchemy.  I was sure I hadn't missed something in the documentation.  Thank you much!